# How can I bind ViewModel to a Generic View in MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm trying to bind a property on an inherited view property that has a generic type.

I get the following error:

> Error XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "ViewModel", or mismatching type between value and property.

```
public abstract class BaseContentView<T> : ContentView where T : BaseVm
{
    public T ViewModel
    {
        get => (T)GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        set => SetValue(ViewModelProperty, BindingContext = value);
    }
    public BindableProperty ViewModelProperty { get; set; } = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ViewModel), typeof(T), typeof(BaseContentView<T>));
}

public partial class MyModelView : BaseContentView<MyModelVm>
{ }

public partial class MyModelVm : BaseVm
{ 
}

public partial class HomeVm : BaseVm
{ 
    public MyModelVm SelectedMyModel { get; set; }
}

public partial class HomePage : ContentView
{ 
}
```

```xaml
    <ContentPage x:Class="HomePage">
      <v:MyModelView ViewModel="{Binding SelectedMyModel}" />
      <!--           ^ Error here                        /-->
    </ContentPage>
```

I this case *`T`* is `MyModelVm` so `ViewModel` property should be assignable to a `MyModelVm` in a `BaseContentView<MyModelVm>` from which `MyModelView` inherits.

Why this error, am I missing something about the property, its returning type or declaring type?

Comment: I don't think the problem is generics. Copy all the related classes, and remove all `<generic>` stuff. You'll get the same message, I'm 99% sure. I don't think you have a BindingContext that makes sense. ViewModel' binding is `SelectedMyModel`, which is in the page, but you have modelviews, so your BindingContext is probably a vm. Something needs to change, but I'm not sure what from your code. (Too hard to think it through, given generics.) Get that to work. OR post a new question, with that non-generic code. Then go back and make the same changes to the generic version.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I updated my code to use the HomeVm. I also tried with non generic ViewModels but I must be in the 1% since I still get the same error. I could post another question but I think that ViewModel property type has less chance to match.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70347196/how-can-i-bind-a-property-to-a-view-model-in-maui