# How can I bind a property to a view model in MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, maui

I'm trying to bind a property to a view model.

I get the following error:

> Error XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "ViewModel", or mismatching type between value and property.

```
public abstract class BaseTestView : ContentView
{
    public BaseVm ViewModel
    {
        get => (BaseVm)GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        set => SetValue(ViewModelProperty, BindingContext = value);
    }
    public static BindableProperty ViewModelProperty { get; set; } = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ViewModel), typeof(BaseVm), typeof(BaseTestView));
}
```

```xaml
<v:BaseTestView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
    x:Class="MyProject.Views.ChildTestView"
    x:DataType="vm:ChildTestVm">
    <v:BaseTestView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="{Binding Foo}" />
      </StackLayout>
  </v:BaseTestView.Content>
</v:BaseTestView>




public partial class ChildTestView : BaseTestView
{
    public ChildTestView() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class ChildTestVm : BaseVm
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public ChildTestVm()
    {
        Title = "Test";
        Foo = "some stuff";
    }
}

public class HomeVm : BaseVm
{ 
    public ChildTestVm Tested { get; set; }
}
```

```xaml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
    x:Class="MyProject.Pages.HomePage"
    x:DataType="HomeVm">
    <ContentPage.Content>
      <StackLayout>
          <v:ChildTestView ViewModel="{Binding Tested}" />
          <!--             ^ Error here               /-->
      </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>




public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{ 
}
```

Any idea of what this error means and how to fix it?

Comment: do you want Bindable for the entire view or a particular stack Layout?

Comment: @SheikMydeenMuthu HomePage has its HomeVm viewmodel and a part of the page (ChildTestView) should be bound to ChildTestVm provided by `Tested`.

Comment: I'm not really up to date on Maui but shouldn't the setter just be:  set => SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); And then in childview you have to bind BindingContext to ViewModelProperty  in xaml?

Comment: @T.Schwarz `BindingContext = value` has for value `value` so the setter sets BindingContext and ViewModelProperty at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried some experiments, but failed to figure out why it gave that complaint - every variation I tried also gave that error.

---

Instead, do it this way:

First, set the `BindingContext` of ChildTestView:

```
<v:ChildTestView BindingContext="{Binding Tested}" />
```

That data-binds ChildTestView to the ChildTestVm from Tested.

If you also need access to the Vm for code behind, do it this way:

ChildTestView.xaml.cs:

```
private ChildTestVm ViewModel => (ChildTestVm)BindingContext;
```

Now in methods of ChildTestView, you can use `ViewModel.Foo`.

---

NOTE: If you *dynamically* change `Tested`:

If you have code anywhere that does `Tested = ...` AFTER HomePage is loaded and visible, then getting that to work requires `Tested` setter to do `OnPropertyChanged();` (or other MVVM data binding mechanism). This is necessary to inform XAML of changes.

Comment: Ok, that's a work around, if I can't find better I'm using it. Thanks for trying.